# c# webservice receive complex array

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm trying to pass an array of object to my web service.

```
var bookingResponse = Service.BookOrder(
    User, Password, Header, order.ToArray(), 1,
    order.OrderId, order.CalculatedID(SessionRO));
```

On the Service:

```
public orderreturn BookOrder(
    string username, string password, OrderHeader order,
    OrderDetail[] order, int extSystemID, int extOrderID, int eventID)
```

Although order has data on the sending side it is coming back as null/empty on the receiving side. Any suggestions?

Comment: Debug. Look at `order`, expand the enumerable, and check there really are elements inside it. Then come back and ask a real question.

Comment: why isnt my service able to read order.ToArray() ?

Comment: there is nothing inside order when i expand it on debug

Comment: order.ToArray() is not empty when im passing it through

Comment: Is OrderDetail a serializable class?

Comment: Is it WCF service? WCFTestClient.exe will help you to pass desired inputs and debug it.

Comment: @Samw: to be a useful question, all of these obvious details that you're having to provide in comments should be part of the original question.

Comment: is the OrderDetail class marked for serialization ? If not user the `Serializable` attribute on the class and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For arrays of custom types to pass you need to mark them with [DataContract] and the properties with [DataMember].

This might get you started;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx

Comment: ive marked the OrderDetail cass as [Serializable] and no lines are coming through

Comment: thanks for this read the site and managed to sort my error